# Trying to set one background-size property equal to another

Tags: css, dynamic, background-size

I am styling a text element and I want to make a fancy corner. I have come up with this code as a solution.

```
.top-corner {
background:
linear-gradient(to left, black 6px, transparent 6px) 100% 0,
linear-gradient(to bottom, black 6px, transparent 6px) 100% 0;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 40px 40px;
width: fit-content;
padding-right: 20px;
```

}

It looks good an I have no initial problem with it.

https://fwb.crazychickentech.com/test/

The problem occurs when I start changing the font size. What I really want to do is something like this.

background-size: "this in px" = that -> 50%; - So basically, I want the first value (top) to be what every the second value (right) is but in pixels (not a percentage because then it would be 50% of the width.

---

I have been reading as much as I can but I'm just not getting anywhere (or understanding it).

I did look at some jQuery, but if I am totally honest, that's not my strong point.

I was also thinking of making a second div or something beside it, but at this point I'm worried I may be making things more complex than they need to be and I'm not thinking clearly.

Any suggestions or thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks all,

Happy Coding!

Comment: Looking at the link you posted, is the left one correct and the right one not? Is it incorrect because there is no space between the text and the corner? This can be resolved by changing the margin.

Comment: The right one is NOT preferable, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo element can do this:

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
}

h1::before,
h1::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50%;
  width: 5px;
  background: red;
}

h1::after {
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: translate(100%) rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<h1>A title here</h1>

<h1 style="font-size:50px">A title here</h1>


<h1 style="font-size:100px">A title here</h1>
```